# unable to save decimal (10,2) in SQL azure database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am using SQL azure database for my web application, and the `Prize` column is a `decimal(10, 2)` datatype.

When I try to save a number `1234567890.11` is shows the following error:

> Numeric arithmetic causes truncation.

but while saving saving a number of type (8,2) it is working fine.

Comment: [Read the official docs on `DECIMAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) and learn what the `decimal(10, 2)` really allows you to store ....

Answer (score 5):

To save value `1234567890.11` you need `DECIMAL(12,2)` or larger.

First number (precision) is the total number of digits that the value can contain (in your case 10+2=12). Second number (scale) is the maximum number of digits to the right of the decimal point (in your case that's 2).